# Multiple Text Box one Validation Property by VAB ENTLIB 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

```
   First Name
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"
                runat="server"
                Width="128px">
   </asp:TextBox> <br />
   Last Name
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2"
                runat="server"
                Width="128px">
    </asp:TextBox> <br />
    Location
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3"
                 runat="server"
                 Width="128px">
    </asp:TextBox> <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1"
                runat="server"
                OnClick="Button1_Click"
                Text="Validate" />
```

On Clicking The `Button Validate` It Should Validate The Above Three Text Box By Using Single String Validator From Validation Application Block Using Entity Library 5.0 in Code Basis,

I am Having Code in Validating the three text By creating three String Validator Property in Validation Application Block(ENTLIB 5.0) and saving that in web.cofig File

Help Me Out From this problem

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

The following is a simple example that associates a validator with an object and then validates that object. It assumes that you will resolve the MyExample class through the Unity container to inject an instance of the Validation Application Block ValidatorFactory class.
The code creates a new Customer object and validates it using the Validation Application Block facade. Because the string length validator attribute is applied, the block checks that the length of the customer name is between 0 and 20 characters. In this case, the customer name is illegal because it is too long. The application throws an exception that notifies you of the error.

```
   using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators;
public class Customer
{
  [StringLengthValidator(0, 20)]
  public string CustomerName;

  public Customer(string customerName)
  {
    this.CustomerName = customerName;
  }
}

public class MyExample
{
  private ValidatorFactory factory;

  public MyExample(ValidatorFactory valFactory)
  {
    factory = valFactory;
  }

  public void MyMethod()
  {
    Customer myCustomer = new Customer("A name that is too long");
    Validator<Customer> customerValidator 
                        = factory.CreateValidator<Customer>();

    // Validate the instance to obtain a collection of validation errors.
    ValidationResults r = customerValidator.Validate(myCustomer);
    if (!r.IsValid)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation error found.");
    }
  }
}
```

The source is [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664378%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)

Or you can reffer [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256355/Microsoft-Enterprise-Library-5-0-Introduction-to-V) link too...